# Creating Word Cloud in Python --- Making Words Different Sizes?

Tags: python, pytagcloud

I am trying to create a word cloud in python using [pytagcloud](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytagcloud/). With my current cloud, I can generate a cloud, but the words all are the same size.
How can I alter the code so that my words' sizes appear in relation to their frequency?

My text file already has the words with their respective frequency counts already in it, the format is like "George, 44" newline "Harold, 77", newline, "Andrew, 22", newline, etc. However, when it displays the word, it also displays the frequency with it.

```
with open ("MyText.txt", "r") as file:
   Data =file.read().replace('\n', '')

tags = make_tags(get_tag_counts(Data), maxsize=150)

create_tag_image(tags, 'Sample.png', size=(1200, 1200),background=(0, 0, 0, 255),  fontname='Lobstero', rectangular=True)

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('Sample.png')
```

Comment: Where are `make_tag`, `get_tag_counts`, and `create_tag_image` defined?

Comment: Try opening MyText.txt as a csv file, so you get rows in which the name and frequency are associated but distinct.

Comment: @Taylor Welcome to Stack Overflow! You _must_ include your import statements or mention the library you are using. It was _not_ obvious that you were using this library -- without this information we can't help you! Be sure to upvote and accept good answers and ask for help on the meta if you need it.

Comment: Can't save it as .csv, I am on a windows machine. Also, I am using the pytagcloud library

Comment: FYI for new visitors, now there is a `wordcloud` package I would use instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the result into a tuple. Using your question as input text we get the expected result:

```
from pytagcloud import create_tag_image, make_tags
from pytagcloud.lang.counter import get_tag_counts

TEXT = '''I am trying to create a word cloud in python. With my current cloud, I can generate a cloud, but the words all are the same size. How can I alter the code so that my words' sizes appear in relation to their frequency?'''

counts = get_tag_counts(TEXT)
tags = make_tags(counts, maxsize=120)
create_tag_image(tags, 'cloud_large.png', size=(900, 600), fontname='Lobster')
```

[image]

It is worth looking at the variable `counts`:

```
[('cloud', 3), 
('words', 2), 
('code', 1), 
('word', 1), 
('appear', 1), ...
```

which is simply a list of tuples. Since your input text file contains a list of tuples, you simply need to pass that information into `make_tags`.

**Edit:** You can read a file like this

```
counts = []
with open("tag_file.txt") as FIN:
   for line in FIN:
       # Assume lines look like: word, number
       word,n = line.strip().split()
       word = word.replace(',','')
       counts.append([word,int(n)])
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work. The words are in a file, separated. If I just enter them as a string, this ignores their respective frequency. When I tried your code, it didn't generate a word cloud. Just for the sake of clarity: each word in my list is listed only once, with its frequency from a corpus directly beside it and separated by a comma

Comment: @Taylor I think your problem is reading in the file. If you post some sample code that mimics your frequency table we can go from there. I'll add a small example that would show how to read a file though.

Comment: The items in my text file involve a string and an integer. The integer needs to somehow affect the size of the words in the word cloud, as each word has a different predetermined frequency. If I turn them into a string as your demonstrated, each word would occur only once and therefore not affect the sizing. That is not what I need

Comment: The integer _will_ change the sizing if you pass in the tuple `counts`. You might not be casting it to an int so the module thinks the number is a string.

Comment: That's more helpful, but when I tried you edited code above, it then told me that there were too many values to unpack. I have 98 lines --- anyway to remedy that?

Comment: The code that I used to read in the file is listed above. Is it easier if we talk about this via private chat?

Comment: @Taylor sorry, chat is blocked at my current location. "Too many values to unpack" means that your text file doesn't follow the exact format of "word count", maybe you have a header line that says "# my info" or a line with too many fields, "word word count". Post a few **raw** lines of the text file into your question.

Comment: Bill, 310 (newline), Andrew, 4022 (newline) Frank, 818(newline) George, 1345

Comment: I updated the code to try and guess what the problem is. I stripped the line, maybe you have extra characters you are not aware of at the ends, and I removed the commas. If this doesn't work, upload the text file somewhere and I can look at it.

Comment: Hooked, I can't upload the file anywhere. But for reference, it's an excel file with the names in column one and their frequency count in column two. Please help, I need this project done soon. Also, even when I reduced the number of items in the excel sheet, it still said that i couldnt handle the data

Comment: Hey hooked could you please help me?